# How to pass json data to jasper report using rest

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to jasper. I have created a jasper report using JSON data source and pushed it to server. Is there a way to pass JSON data to the jasper report using rest call? I cannot find any example to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a report that has a `json` or `jsonql` query, what you can do is to provide a default value for the `JSON_INPUT_STREAM` builtin parameter based on the value of a another parameter that you create in the report.  Something like this:

```
<parameter name="JsonData" class="java.lang.String">
</parameter>
<parameter name="JSON_INPUT_STREAM" class="java.io.InputStream">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new ByteArrayInputStream($P{JsonData}.getBytes("UTF-8"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString language="json">
    <![CDATA[..json query..]]>
</queryString>
```

Than you'd need to create an input control for the `JsonData` parameter in the JasperReports Server report.  If you have that you can pass a value for `JsonData` when running the report via REST:

```
  "parameters": {
    "reportParameter": [
      {
        "name": "JsonData",
        "value": [
          "{..json data..}"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```